# How to fix responsive problem in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and I have the following jumbotron class:

```css
.rounded-circle{
    vertical-align: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -150px;
    top: -50px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="jumbotron rounded-0">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/500px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png" alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    this is mobile way of the container and other line
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

With this syntax, my desktop view is displaying as well following,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUrAe.png

but in my mobile view, it is not displaying in correct position as following https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaRuW.png

then how could I view my image and descriptions on all devices (desktop, tab and phone) as well, I need in the small device top image and then description under the image.

**edited image**
[image: new desktop view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong here to use `position: absolute` with `col`, flex-box gives you the utility to make the behavior you are trying to reach without `position: absolute`,

**First** add the class `align-items-center` beside class `row` (this will align center vertically)

**Second** add the class `col-12` to the columns (make the description below the image for smaller size)

**Then** optionally, you can add the classes `text-center` and `text-md-left` (on bigger sizes it will align left and on smaller it will be center)

```css
.rounded-circle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="jumbotron rounded-0">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row align-items-center text-center text-md-left">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/500px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png" alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
    this is mobile way of the container and other line
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is okay but have some problem in the desktop vertions, that means in desktop view image is displaing in the right corner of the div section. I need left corner of the div section here

Comment: currently, the image is on the left side of its parent which is `<div class="col-12 col-md-4">` I have just check

Comment: in my case it is not I have another <div class="container"> before the jumbotrong div. is it the problem?

Comment: Can you take screenshot of how its been displaying

Comment: Im confused actually it’s looking good, if you could draw something on the screenshot to clarify exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: okay I need image left corner of the jumbotrone

Comment: If you want the image to be at the left edge of jumbotron, then of course you have to remove the `<div class="container"> ` because it has `max-width` value which will prevent the image from being at the left edge of the jumbotron